When I use Jupyterlab in google chrome to write code, It Raise "SyntaxError: invaild non-printable character U+00A0", but safari has not this problem
When I use Jupyter lab in chrome browser, it always autoadd special character in my code resulting a SyntaxError

SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+00A0


When I delete this special Character, It sometimes auto appear.
So I use Safari to write code with jupyterlab, the special character can be delete, and never auto appear.
I use Mac os14.5
Google Chrome     126.0.6478.127 (arm64)
iterm2 with nvim
I use Safari to write code with jupyterlab, the special character can be delete, and never auto appear.
